# Aligning text in legend using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, legend, arcgis-10.4

I am working in ArcMap 10.4.1.  Trying to align the text in a legend.  I want my title to be centred and the text next to the patches to be aligned left. The normal buttons to select alignment are missing from the links to change size and colour of text etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the legend alignment from the beginning of creating legend. Here is the screenshot from the Legend Wizard:

[image]

To change the alignment of the patches you can follow these steps after creating the legend:

1. Right click on the legend box.
2. Select Convert To Graphics
3. Select Ungroup. You will have to ungroup all elements, until you get control of each element

After you ungroup each element (texts and symbols) you can align them manually by dragging.

Comment: Thank you for  the information.  I had already made the legend but the title was a long one and I have had to divide it up onto different lines.  This looks odd left aligned and I wanted to centre it for a better appearance.  Is the only way to do this to start the legend all over again?

Comment: You can follow the 3 steps I have mentioned before. After ungrouping, right click on the title, select properties where you will find the alignment options. But it may not work sometimes, it is better you do the alignment from the beginning.

Comment: I am curios to know that why your legend title is so long. Generally we only write "Legend".